# Problem with rendering markers | React Native

Tags: react-native

I use for maps in react native-react-native-maps.

I need to render markers to the map from json file.

But I have a error occurs:

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource.map')
```

The complete code block looks like this:

```
 {this.state.dataSource.map(item => (
 <Marker coordinate={item.latlng} />
   ))}
```

Coordinates for the marker I take from the json file, maybe the error is here ?

```
"latlng": {
      "latitude": 53.6937,
      "longitude": -336.1968
    },
```

I need your help.Full code:

```
export default class MapScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "Map",
      region: {
        latitude: 53.67,
        longitude: 23.83,
        latitudeDelta: 0.04,
        longitudeDelta: 0.09
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            dataSource: responseJson
          },
          function() {}
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#1f1f1f" }}>
        <View style={styles.Header}>
          <HeaderProfile title={title} />
        </View>
        <MapView
          region={this.state.region}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}

        >
          {this.state.dataSource.map(item => (
            <Marker coordinate={item.latlng} />
          ))}
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call map() on `undefined`.

You have few options:

1. Define a dummy `dataSource` in state:

   ```
   this.state = { 
     dataSource: [],
     ...
   ```
2. Check that dataSource is defined before calling `map()`:

   ```
   {this.state.dataSource && this.state.dataSource.map...
   ```

If `dataSource` is an Object. `map()` only works on arrays. You need to iterate through the Object: somthing like

```
Object.keys(dataSource).forEach(key => {
  return (<Marker coordinate={dataSource[key].latlan} />)
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Markers appeared on the map. But there is one mistake:

Failed prop type: The prop `coordinate` is marked as required in `MapMarker`, but its value is `undefined`.